# Is it possible to use plocal Engine in OrientDB cluster mode?

Tags: orientdb

I would like to access a distributed graph (master-master replicated) via OrientGraph **plocal** (**embededed**) for each node. Is this even possible?

I managed to setup hazlecast and orientserver clustering as described [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Distributed-Configuration.html) but the documentation does not include examples on how to interact with the cluster when using plocal. When i try to access the database via plocal it states that the database is already opened (i assume by the OrientServer).

Is it possible to use a plocal connection with a embedded distributed graph? If so what steps are needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible and actually it's one of the best way you can use OrientDB if you're developing with Java. How to use it? Everything is transparent, so start an Embedded server and continue using OrientDB with plocal and OrientDB server will take care of synchronization and replication.